# What do 3 dots (...) specify in a c++ function?

Tags: c++, function, parameters

What do the 3 dots (...) specify in this function ?

```
void fun(int A,const char *B,...);
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments

Comment: Since C++11 variadic templates should be used instead for typesafety https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack